# how to solve cursor work only first time in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have declare a cursor in one procedure and make a loop inside it. but when i execute procedure cursor
occur only first time what happen to this i want it occur everytime when procedure is executed.

```
DECLARE SUP_CUR CURSOR SCROLL DYNAMIC  FOR SELECT * FROM @saleSup
DECLARE @SUP_TEMP AS INT
OPEN SUP_CUR
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0 
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM SUP_CUR INTO @SUP_TEMP

    SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT saleRepId),userId   FROM @tabletemp WHERE userId = @SUP_TEMP GROUP BY userId 

END 
CLOSE SUP_CUR;
DEALLOCATE SUP_CUR;
```

Answer (score 3):

Put FETCH NEXT to end of loop and add first FETCH

```
DECLARE SUP_CUR CURSOR SCROLL DYNAMIC  FOR SELECT * FROM @saleSup
DECLARE @SUP_TEMP AS INT

OPEN SUP_CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM SUP_CUR INTO @SUP_TEMP

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0 
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT saleRepId),userId   FROM @tabletemp WHERE userId = @SUP_TEMP GROUP BY userId 

    FETCH NEXT FROM SUP_CUR INTO @SUP_TEMP
END 
CLOSE SUP_CUR;
DEALLOCATE SUP_CUR;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `cursor` like this. You need to add fetch before the start of while loop to fetch the `first row` and at the end  of `while loop` add `FETCH NEXT` to fetch the `next row`

```
DECLARE @SUP_TEMP AS INT
DECLARE SUP_CUR CURSOR SCROLL DYNAMIC FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   @saleSup

OPEN SUP_CUR

-- Perform the first fetch.
FETCH NEXT FROM SUP_CUR INTO @SUP_TEMP

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      SELECT Count (DISTINCT saleRepId),
             userId
      FROM   @tabletemp
      WHERE  userId = @SUP_TEMP
      GROUP  BY userId

      -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
      FETCH NEXT FROM SUP_CUR INTO @SUP_TEMP
  END

CLOSE SUP_CUR;

DEALLOCATE SUP_CUR;
```

Answer (score 0):

now i know what problem with it. i just put

```
FETCH NEXT FROM SUP_CUR INTO @SUP_TEMP
```

before start loop and move FETCH NEXT to below select statement in loop and that work properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use a cursor (they are bad practice anyway), try:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT saleRepId),userId   
FROM @tabletemp 
GROUP BY userId
```